# Get GitHub account using StackExchange API

Tags: java, stackexchange-api

I am trying to use the **StackExchange API** to retrieve the **GitHub link** a user has set in his **profile**.

I am talking about this one:

[image: Profile picture]

However I'm not finding methods to retrieve that data. I'm also not sure whether the API offers access to that data.

Here are some documentations I found:

- https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/users
- [https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/?order=desc&sort=reputation&site=stackoverflow](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/%3Cuser_id%3E?order=desc&sort=reputation&site=stackoverflow)

So can I use this API to retrieve the GitHub account of a user?

Comment: I think he tries to use said **StackExchange API** to retrieve the **GitHub account** a user has set in his **profile**. He wants to know whether the API offers methods for this. OP can you confirm that? If so, you might make this more clear in your question.

Comment: Yes it is. StackExchange API

Comment: I see that now. Hopefully one of the edits sets the `stackexchange-api` tag on the question. Though, the answer is probably "this is not exposed through the Users API" if it isn't specifically called out in the API as a field.

Comment: I'm not an expert on this API but I don't think that it offers such a method. I mean the [https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/user](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/user) lists all available fields, doesn't it? I can see a `website_url` field but nothing with GitHub.

Comment: You might have better luck asking this question on [meta.stackoverflow.com](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: Yes, GitHub account doesn`t exists

Comment: I have a small rating to create an issue

Comment: Well, that is of course understandable. However it does not mean that you therefore should post the question here.

Answer (score 3):

The **StackExchange API** does **not offer access** to that data.

As you already have posted

- https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/2411243?site=stackoverflow

is all information you can get from a user.

The [official documentation](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/user) lists all available fields and explains them. A *GitHub field* is **not among them**. Here is the [complete documentation](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs) listing all available methods.

You will need to use different APIs or techniques to retrieve that data.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in the API for a users a git hub account.